# How to use MapControllers on a sub path?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have an application which uses the Uno platform for a UI and I want to have an additional REST API for it to communicate.

Right now, when I have a controller like:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class AwesomeController: ControllerBase {
  ...
}
```

the

```cs
app.MapControllers();
```

installs this as `https://mycompany.com/awesome`

How do I install all my controllers to a subpath, like: `https://mycompany.com/api/awesome` without putting the `api/` bit in every `[Route]` attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to register the following [conventional-route](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0#set-up-conventional-route) in the `Program.cs`:

```cs
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "api/{controller=Awesome}/{action?}/{id?}");

app.MapControllers();
app.Run();
```

After registering this route remove the route attributes in the controller class:

```cs
//[ApiController]
//[Route("[controller]")]
public class AwesomeController: ControllerBase {
  ...
}
```

Now you can use:

```
https://mycompany.com/api/awesome
```

or

```
https://mycompany.com/api/another_controller
```